# Trying to get Apache Atlas working with standalone Hive Metastore

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, atlas

I've been working on getting Apache Hive Metastore to work with Apache Atlas.  The setup I have is a docker-compose working with trino, mysql, minio, and hive metastore. I'm able to get metadata into the metastore with no issue.  Where I'm getting lost is with the Atlas Listener — pushes Hive metastore events to Apache Atlas. I compiled Apache Atlas with maven and have all the hooks. Is there a way to do this without kafka or does kafka have to be in this architecture?  Also the documentation out there is very limited so if someone has actual configs I would really like to see how it's setup.

Here is the docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "2"

services:
  trino-coordinator:
    image: 'trinodb/trino:412'
    hostname: trino-coordinator
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./etc:/etc/trino
    networks:
      - trino-network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: metastore_db
    networks:
      - trino-network

  # make sure that you specify correct volume to be mounted
  minio:
    image: 'minio/minio:latest'
    hostname: minio
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    networks:
      - trino-network

  hive-metastore:
    build: .
    image: hive-metastore:latest
    ports:
    - 9083:9083
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - trino-network

networks:
  trino-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Are you getting some error that is referring to some Kafka client action? If not, then I wouldn't think it's required

Comment: @OneCricketeer It's not throwing any errors but the little documentation that is out there says you need Kafka to transport the events.  I've setup a different docker-compose with all the parts but to no joy.  I've come across this [Drone Fly](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/drone-fly-decoupling-event-listeners-from-the-hive-metastore-43b0107b15e2)

Comment: There's documentation on Kafka hooks, but hooks are not required for Hive metastore operations https://atlas.apache.org/#/HookKafka That just makes Atlas know about Kafka topics

Comment: Otherwise, 1) Show your full file 2) settings here seem clear to me, but use Zookeeper connection string (which would be the same for a Kafka cluster). But Zookeeper is no longer required for Kafka, so I suggest seeing if there's a JIRA in Atlas project to fix this https://atlas.apache.org/#/HookHive

Comment: is it solved? Is it possible to integrate HMS Standalone version with Atlas to push events Atlas?

Comment: I haven't been able to get anywhere with this.  I have been looking at https://open-metadata.org/